# JCOP 3 pre-personalization secid p60

Tags: applet, javacard, jcop

I want to know how to pre-personalization jcop 3 card i tried JCOP 2 pre-personalization script but it didn't work and searched and i didn't find any results to it so far . i tried this tutorial https://re-ws.pl/2017/09/importunderstanding-jcop-pre-personalization/
it worked in jcop 2 but didn't work in jcop 3

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you give us some more information?

Comment: Just a warning for would be answerers of this rather broad question: generally such information is contained in documentation of NXP that can only be obtained by signing a non-disclosure agreement. Mohamed, why not ask NXP or the vendor of your JCOP chips?

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica i want also to know should i install security domain to host the applet ?

Comment: Generally you would use the Card Manager for that. The CM is an SD by itself. If you need a *separate SD* depends, of course, on the use case (if you cannot think of a reason then you probably don't need it).

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica thank you maarten:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reach out to your NXP representative and request they push the JCOP 3 SecID P60 User Guidance and Administration manual to your DocStore account. You will need to create a DocStore account in this instance. This is a NDA-covered document and you will also require the JCOP Tools package to run the scripting - which can be requested from tools.jcop@nxp.com. Your NXP representative may also have sample scripts for the JCShell program to assist in initialisation.