# Can't load my applet in smartcard (6D00 response)

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform

My applet is ready but **I can't load it into my smart card**.

My card's Specification:

-Java Card 3.0.4 Classic

-GP2.2.1

I am using gp.exe but even when I try to execute any command of **global platform** for example:

> gp -list
> gp -info
> I get this response:

GlobalPlatformPro 325fe84
Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 1.8.0_291 by Oracle Corporation
Error: Could not SELECT default selected: 0x6D00 (Invalid Instruction)

Can any one help me to figure out the problem please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not download applet (.cap file) into the smart card: SW 6D 00 (Invalid Instruction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617917/could-not-download-applet-cap-file-into-the-smart-card-sw-6d-00-invalid-ins)

Comment: This is again the same questions. Have you followed the instructions and passed the AID for the ISD?