# Can not load an applet on a JavaCard

Tags: java, applet, smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

I am trying to uplaod an applet that i made onto a real smart card. I tried with Simulators like JCWDE and CREF and it worjed perfectly.
But with my smart card, even though the system (i'm using the GlobalPlatformPro tool to load via the gp -load  command) recongnizes the card, it always displays this errors for each operation i want to do and i don't know how to solve it.

This is the result with GlobalPlateform (with -d -v options) :

```
C:\Java>gp -load javacard -d -v
GlobalPlatformPro 18.09.14-0-gb439b52
Running on Windows 10 10.0 amd64, Java 1.8.0_291 by Oracle Corporation
# Detected readers from JNA2PCSC
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contact Reader 0
[ ] JAVACOS Virtual Contactless Reader 1
[*] OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0
SCardConnect("OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A
SCardBeginTransaction("OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0")
Reader: OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0
ATR: 3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3B7D9400005744290830869312C090111E1A

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (16ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
[DEBUG] GlobalPlatform - Auto-detected ISD: A000000003000000
Warning: no keys given, using default test key 404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 007D0897841EECAB 00
A<< (0000+2) (31ms) 6D00
INITIALIZE UPDATE failed: 0x6D00 (Invalid INStruction)
```

This the result with PyAptduTool :

```
Select CardManager begin...
Select CardManager successful.
Download Cap begin...
Download Cap successful.
Install Applet begin...
Install Applet successful.
Select Applet begin...
Select Applet successful.
```

I tried with gpj and this is the output :

```
Found card in terminal: OMNIKEY AG Smart Card Reader USB 0
ATR: 3B 7D 94 00 00 57 44 29 08 30 86 93 12 C0 90 11 24 1F
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 82
Failed to select Security Domain GP211 A0 00 00 01 51 00 00 , SW: 6A 82
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6A 82
Failed to select Security Domain GemaltoXpressPro A0 00 00 00 18 43 4D 00 , SW: 6A 82
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00
Successfully selected Security Domain OP201a A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 6A 40 39 0E 99 CC 40 D0
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6D 00
javax.smartcardio.CardException: Wrong initialize update, SW: 6D 00
        at net.sourceforge.gpj.cardservices.GlobalPlatformService.openSecureChannel(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.gpj.cardservices.GlobalPlatformService.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You might need to pre-personalize your card...see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67617917/5128464)

Comment: Otherwise: contact your provider for the configuration of the card.

Comment: @vlp Thanks for anwsering. I've foolowed the link but i dont't really understand what pre-personalization is and how i could do it on my card. Could you please explain me ?

Comment: @SalomonDiei You card is in a raw (unfused) state. You need to set e.g. ISD keys, communication protocol (T=0,T=1, speeds...) etc. To do this you need a "Transport Key" (from your card supplier) and respective "Administrator Manual" from NXP. It is not possible to tell you more as it is covered by NDA. Ask NXP directly.

Comment: @vpl Thanks you for anwsering. I've found the transfort key, but don't know how i could set ISD keys, commmication protocol via gp CLI.

Comment: @vpl I tried with PyApduTool and it works, i can upload the applet on the card. But it still displays the same error when i try with gp CLI

Comment: @SalomonDiei If your applet works when loaded by another tool then definitely your card works ok and pre-personalization mentioned above is not needed. Can you edit your question with traces of both PyApduTool and GlobalPlatformPro (ideally with all APDUs -- i.e. `-d -v` options for GlobalPlatformPro)?

Comment: It is possible that ISD is wrongly selected and `--sdaid` option might be needed for GlobalPlatformPro. Which smart card are you using?

Comment: Is there a mean were i could contact you directly, for more direct explainations and guidance ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't load a Java Card Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68438130/cant-load-a-java-card-applet)

Comment: The card is a ID-One Cosmo V7.0 from Oberthur Technologies

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 It's actualy the same issue, the anwser solves none of the questions.